# query that is splitting a column into two

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hello I have an ID column and an amount column at the moment. 
A value is represented as a Debit if the amount is positive. A credit if the amount is negative. I'm wondering how can I "Split" my amount column.

```
Select * from Test.dbo.Accounts
```

Produces

```
ID  | Amount
 1  |   500
 2  |  -600
```

So Item 1 is a Debit, Item two is a credit. I want to query the Database so that it displays as followed

```
ID  | Debit  | Credit
 1  | 500    | null
 2  | null   |-600
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a case statement to find which column the amount belongs in:

```
SELECT  id ,
        CASE WHEN amount >= 0 THEN amount
             ELSE NULL
        END AS debit ,
        CASE WHEN amount < 0 THEN amount
             ELSE NULL
        END AS credit
FROM    Test.dbo.Accounts
```

I assumed 0 should go in debits but that'd be your call.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select ID, Amount as Debit, null as Credit
From Account
Where Amount >= 0

Union All

Select ID, null as Debit, Amount as Credit
From Account
Where Amount < 0
```

Comment: Fix name of column in where, and I think is better to use it without cast and replace `'null'` with `null`. Like this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/984f7/3

Comment: to be honest I was being a bit pedantic, I don't like seeing the value null in results!